# Pexpect ssh login opens password prompt window

Tags: ssh, pexpect

I have a simple `pexpect` script to ssh into a system:

```
    p = pexpect.spawn ("ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null admin@%s" % (system))
    p.logfile_read = fout
    p.setecho(True)
    time.sleep (5)

    i = p.expect ([VM_PAT_TM_PROMPT_USER, STANDBY_PROMPT, 'password:', pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'Error'], timeout=60)
```

It works on some of the systems. However, now it started popping up this small window with password prompt. While that window is waiting for the password the `p.expect` call times out.
Is there any way to prevent this extra popup window?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.
This is the same issue as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21422782/prevent-git-from-popping-up-gnome-password-box). The popup comes from the SSH settings, `SSH_ASKPASS` in particular. You can find more details at the [SSH man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ssh1.html).